# How to create touchscreen in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

I have a program that is written in vb.net winforms.
I've been asked to add touchscreen abilities to the program(mainly open keyboard when we are on text box and close the keyboard when we are off the text box)

i've tried to use Process.Start("c:\Windows\System32\osk.exe") and it works
but i can't get it to close (tried to use Process.Close()/CloseMainWindow()/Kill())

is there another way to make it work or easier is to implement to gui in wpf?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it.  You of course need to save the return value of Process.Start() so you have a proper reference to the process object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm saving the return value and when i leave the textbox i'm tring yo close it but it doen't close it, when i'm debugging when i use close function it does nothing when i use closemainwindow it thorw me "process has exited, so the reqeusted..."  and when i use kill it thorw me "cannot process request ..." and the osk still open

Comment: It is very important to use the Exited event so you'll know not to try to kill a process that has terminated.  When you have that, you'll no doubt discover that it quits a lot quicker than you assumed.  Project > Properties > Compile tab > Target CPU = AnyCPU and untick Prefer 32 bit.  Or use "c:\windows\sysnative\osk.exe", do prefer Environment.GetFolderPath() instead of hard-coding c:\windows.

Comment: The project is allready in AnyCPU and the "Prefer 32 bit" is uncheck and disabled, I've found strange thing when i start the process, the exited value is true. maybe that's the problem?